# ionic base64togallery plugin not working in android-targetSdkVersion 29

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm using base64-to-gallery to save images for android devices in my ionic app.

Previously it was working fine but now after added `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />`to config.xml file, under android platform, it's not working.

Please kindly help me with it.

Comment: As per the documentation this plugin is deprecated and no longer supported.

Comment: HI, @NajamUsSaqib , yeah that's the thing. Do you know any other way to do it? Please kindly help.

Comment: This might help you: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/150/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-a-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova

Comment: also share your build command error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. To anyone who is struggling, I will explain as below.

As mentioned in the git, https://github.com/Nexxa/cordova-base64-to-gallery , ionic Cordova base64togallery plugin has been discontinued.

And also when trying to submit the ionic mobile app for Android production, it's saying that the target SDK version should be more than 29.

But as usual, if we add `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />` to the config.xml file under the Android platform, **it will not work the base64togallery plugin** (not saving images to your device)

So you have to do like below,

In your ionic project, go to `build.gradle` file (`platforms\android\build.gradle`) and change **defaultTargetSdkVersion** and **defaultCompileSdkVersion** to 29. (as below)

```
defaultTargetSdkVersion=29 
defaultCompileSdkVersion=29
```

And then go to `AndroidManifest.xml` file
(`platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`) and add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the application tag, as showing below.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Then try to build your app for debug or release versions.

Comment: You can Simply Use this Plugin to save Images: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-library